# Python program issue on Windows

Tags: python, windows

Trying to run such simple program on Windows (it works pretty good on my Mac OSX), and here is the program and error message, when cursor stops on `print a`, there is an alert saying end of statement expected. Do I need to do anything special for Python on Windows?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a=[1,2,3]
    print a
```

**Error:**

```
D:\python3.4.0\python.exe C:/Users/mayfv/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py
  File "C:/Users/aaa/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py", line 4
    print a
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Also sometimes the indentation do gets messed up when its a copy paste, happens with me many times, there is nothing wrong with the code, works well with python 2.7 and with python 3.X you need to write as print(a)

Comment: @BrijRajSingh, tried it works when adding (). Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [2to3 - Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 3.4 you need to use `print(a)`
In python 2.7 its `print a`

Comment: works for me. Sorry for blaming Windows. :)

Comment: BTW, yes, on Mac, I am using Python 2.7.x series. And it means I have a lot of stuff to migrate when using print. :(

Comment: @LinMa, Read the difference between python 2.x and 3.x from here https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: @LinMa Glad to help... when migrating make sure you import the right packages